# Librosa's fft and Scipy's fft are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, spectrogram, librosa

Both Librosa and Scipy have the `fft` function, however, they give me a different spectrogram output even with the same signal input.

### Scipy

I am trying to get the spectrogram with the following code

```
import numpy as np                                       # fast vectors and matrices
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                          # plotting
from scipy import fft      

X = np.sin(np.linspace(0,1e10,5*44100))

fs = 44100          # assumed sample frequency in Hz
window_size = 2048  # 2048-sample fourier windows
stride = 512        # 512 samples between windows
wps = fs/float(512) # ~86 windows/second
Xs = np.empty([int(2*wps),2048])

for i in range(Xs.shape[0]):
    Xs[i] = np.abs(fft(X[i*stride:i*stride+window_size]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
plt.imshow(Xs.T[0:150],aspect='auto')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
fig.axes[0].set_xlabel('windows (~86Hz)')
fig.axes[0].set_ylabel('frequency')
plt.show()
```

Then I get the following spectrogram
[image]

### Librosa

Now I try to get the same spectrogram with Librosa

```
from librosa import stft

X_libs = stft(X, n_fft=window_size, hop_length=stride)
X_libs = np.abs(X_libs)[:,:int(2*wps)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
plt.imshow(X_libs[0:150],aspect='auto')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
fig.axes[0].set_xlabel('windows (~86Hz)')
fig.axes[0].set_ylabel('frequency')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Question

The two spectrogram are obviously different, specifically, the Librosa version has an attack at the very beginning.
What causes the difference? I don't see many parameters that I can tune in the documentation for Scipy and Librosa.

Comment: You are using the STFT from librosa, not the FFT. There's a difference, as the STFT often includes windowing and padding. See my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for this is the argument `center` for librosa's [stft](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html). By default it's `True` (along with `pad_mode = 'reflect'`).

From the docs:

> *librosa.core.stft(y, n_fft=2048, hop_length=None, win_length=None, window='hann', center=True, dtype=, pad_mode='reflect')*
>
> **center:boolean**
>
> If True, the signal y is padded so that frame D[:, t] is centered at y[t * hop_length].
>
> If False, then D[:, t] begins at y[t * hop_length]
>
> **pad_mode:string**
>
> If center=True, the padding mode to use at the edges of the signal. By default, STFT uses reflection padding.

Calling the STFT like this

```
X_libs = stft(X, n_fft=window_size, hop_length=stride,
              center=False)
```

does lead to a straight line:

[image: librosa.stft with center = False]

Note that librosa's stft also uses the [Hann window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function) by default. If you want to avoid this and make it more like your Scipy stft implementation, call the stft with a window consisting only of ones:

```
X_libs = stft(X, n_fft=window_size, hop_length=stride,
              window=np.ones(window_size),
              center=False)
```

[image: librosa.stft with center = False and no window function]

You'll notice that the line is thinner.